# VBA for saving customised theme font file as xml for use in different documents

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is it possible to automate this feature using VBA?

[Customise Theme Fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA6MT.png)

#### This is the code I have so far

```vb
    Dim objFSO As Object

    Dim objXMLThemeFontFile As Object

    Dim strFilePath As String = Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\Theme Fonts\"

    Dim strFileName As String = "BrandFonts.xml"

    Dim strFileFullPath = strFilePath & strFileName

    Dim strXML = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
    <a:fontScheme xmlns:a='http//schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main' name='Brand Fonts'>
    <a:majorFont>
    <a:latin typeface='Source Sans Pro'/>
    <a:ea typeface=''/>
    <a:cs typeface=''/>
    </a:majorFont>
    <a:minorFont>
    <a:latin typeface='Source Sans Pro'/>
    <a:ea typeface=''/>
    <a:cs typeface=''/>
    </a:minorFont >
    </a:fontScheme>
    "
    objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    objXMLThemeFontFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFileFullPath)

    objXMLThemeFontFile.Write(CStr(strXML))

    objXMLThemeFontFile.Close()
    
    Dim objPres As Presentation
    
    objPres = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation
    
    objPres.SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeFontScheme.Load(strFileFullPath)
```

#### What works

The xml ThemeFontScheme xml file is written to the correct folder and appears to be structured correctly

#### What doesn't work

The FontScheme 'Brand Fonts' won't show in the font scheme selector when loaded

#### I am getting an error

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in BrandTool.dll but was not handled in user code
The file cannot be opened due to problems with the contents.

This error occurs on this last line of code

```vb
    objPres.SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeFontScheme.Load(strFileFullPath)
```

Comment: What is BrandTool.dll? This is not VBA ...

Comment: BrandTool.dll is the Addin that the vba is run from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was missing the colon after http, you forgot to use "Set" before your set some variables. The code below shows how to implement double quotes in a string. This is working here:

```
Sub MakeFontTheme()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objXMLThemeFontFile As Object
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFileFullPath As String
    Dim strXML As String
    
    strFilePath = Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\Theme Fonts\"
    strFileName = "BrandFonts.xml"
    strFileFullPath = strFilePath & strFileName
    strXML = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?><a:fontScheme xmlns:a=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"" name=""Brand Fonts""><a:majorFont><a:latin typeface=""Source Sans Pro""/><a:ea typeface=""""/><a:cs typeface=""""/></a:majorFont><a:minorFont><a:latin typeface=""Source Sans Pro""/><a:ea typeface=""""/><a:cs typeface=""""/></a:minorFont ></a:fontScheme>"
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objXMLThemeFontFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFileFullPath)
    With objXMLThemeFontFile
        .WriteLine (CStr(strXML))
        .Close
    End With
    Dim objPres As Presentation
    objPres = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation
    objPres.SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeFontScheme.Load (strFileFullPath)
End Sub
```

Comment: John thank you! It worked. You've made my day. I really appreciate the guidance. I'm learning albeit slowly!

Comment: I'm building this as part of an addin in Visual Studio code as a VSTO addin. Visual Studio does suggest to remove the Set option. Is that correct?

Comment: Visual Studio VB is not VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the xml - it will automatically be applied.

```vb
.SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeFontScheme.Load Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\Theme Fonts\SourceSansPro.xml"
```

Comment: Thank you. If the xml doesn't exist how do we save the xml? I added some information to my question above. Can you help?

Comment: But you show the `save`-statement in your question - not sure what your question is ...

Comment: Forgive me I'm a beginner at this. Yes I understand the save and load commands now. I put save because I am trying to save an xml configuration that the screenshot will create. I've added the xml that needs to be saved (added above to my question) and then I can use your suggested load code. I don't want users to have to manually setup the xml font customisation using the built in customise option.

Comment: Btw: I tried `.SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeFontScheme.MajorFont(msoThemeLatin).Name = "Arial"` - for me it works

Comment: I've clarified my question above. Can you help? I really appreciate your time

Comment: Really? I doesn't work for me. I'll try again

Comment: Put the XML text above into a string variable, then write the variable to a file using a Write statement in VBA. MS docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/printstatement

Comment: Hi Steve, Thank you. I successfully write the xml file to the Theme Fonts folder but it doesn't load into the Fonts Menu and change the fonts. Any ideas? I've tried the load method on ThemeFontScheme but no luck. Really appreciate you.

Comment: You can't change the fonts menu that way. Fonts have to be _installed_. If Roboto is not installed on the machine, loading the xml will have no effect!

Comment: Thanks Ike. The fonts are installed. I'm not trying to install them. I'm trying to create and load a theme font scheme. The theme font scheme should set the theme fonts

Comment: When I load the xml I do get an error that says the content can't be read.

Comment: This is the error when loading the xml font scheme. System.ArgumentException: 'The file cannot be opened due to problems with the contents.'

Comment: Updated question with current code

Comment: It sounds like John's answered that problem, correct?